# because my return is [{"singles": [[Object], [Object]]}]

Tags: firebase, react-native, use-effect

I am using a useEffect to get information from a collection and a sub-collection, however, the data return from my sub-collection is being [{"singles": [[Object], [Object]]}]

```
useEffect(() => {
    fireStore
      .collection('users')
      // .where('category','==','band')
      // .where('status','==','approved')
      .where('email','==','marcelomenoli12@gmail.com')
      .get()
      .then( async (musics) => {
        const allSingles = musics.docs.map(async (single) => {
          const items = await single.ref.collection('musics').get();
          return {
            // cover: single.data().cover,
            // name: single.data().bandArtistName,
            singles: items.docs.map((item) => ({
              id: item.id,
              ...item.data(),
            }))
          }
        });
      const filteredSingles = await Promise.all(allSingles);
      setDATA(filteredSingles);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(DATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use more than one then clauses, so every async operation return values. Otherwise inner await responses are not come on time.
I tried to update your code. I hope that helps.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fireStore
      .collection('users')
      .where('email','==','marcelomenoli12@gmail.com')
      .get()
      .then( async (musics) => {
        const allSingles = musics.docs.map(async (single) => {
          return await single.ref.collection('musics').get();
          
      })
      .then((items)=>{
            // cover: single.data().cover,
            // name: single.data().bandArtistName,
            singles: items.docs.map((item) => ({
              id: item.id,
              ...item.data(),
            }))
      })
  }, []);
  console.log(DATA);
```